# Titanium.DB read Blob from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, blob, titanium

I'm developing with SDK 1.6.2

I execute a query using the following SQL

> var dbrows = db.execute('select item_logo , item_id,item_title,item_content   from item');

I successfully get the values for item_id , item_title & item_content. However Ti.API.Info(getFieldByName('item_logo') returns a null value. I have the blob data in SQLLite ITEM table and it is a valid jpeg picture.

Is there any specific processing to be done at Titanium End (Code) to read the Blob data in a loop? Can't find any specific info @ Titanium API docs.

Thanks
Vishnoo

Answer (score 1):

you can do this, but the recommended approach is to store the blob as a file and keep the native file path in the database.

See this response from Appcelerator

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/97041/imageview-sqlite-blob-example-not-working